# How to test if one UIView is being touched by another UIView?

Tags: xcode, events, uiview, touch

I have a custom UIView, holder.

I have another custom UIView from a different class, and the instance is named letter.

When letter touches holder, i want holder to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check that the intersection of the two views' frames is null. Use the `frame` method on the UIView class to get the CGRect frame of each view, then call `CGRectIntersection` to find the rectangles' overlapping area, if any. If they don't touch, the intersection will be the null rectangle (i.e. will return true for `CGRectIsNull`).

Code, untested:

```
// Given UIView * letter, * holder:
CGRect letterFrame = [letter frame];
CGRect holderFrame = [holder frame];
CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(letterFrame, holderFrame);
if(CGRectIsNull(intersection)) {
    // Not touching yet - null intersection
} else {
    // Touching! Do something here
}
```